# Angular 2: hide route component

Tags: apache, angular

I have a website built around angular 2 running on Apache. The same website (and same API) is used by different "groups". Let's say there are two groups: bees and wasps. My angular routing file looks like this:

```
{
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'groupe/1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'groupe',
        children: [
            {
                path: ':groupe',
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        component: HomePage,
                    },
...
```

To access a group, I can then simply go to http://myws.com/group/1 (for bees) and http://myws.com/group/2 (for wasps). Pages are then basically the same for each group (with different content, loaded from an API), like: http://myws.com/group/1/page/21.

Now the tricky part. First I want to access each "group" from a simplified, explicit URL: like http://myws.com/bees. I can do this by adding the following code to the router :

```
{
    path: 'bees',
    redirectTo: 'groupe/1',
    pathMatch: 'prefix'
},
```

Problem is, the route changes in the URL back to /group/1. **Is there a way to make the /bees permanent, hiding /group/1 ?**

Now, I also want to access my bees group from a specific domain, like http://www.bees.com. Pages should render like http://www.bees.com/page/21 **Is there a way with angular or Apache to do this?**

Answer (score 0):

Well, on the Angular side (meaning everything after the .com), you can do like so

```
export const bugRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'bees', canActivate: [MyBeeGuard], children: [
        { path: '', component: BeeHomeComponent },
        { path: '**', component: BeeHomeComponent }
    ]},
    { path: 'wasps', canActivate: [MyWaspGuard], children: [
        { path: '', component: WaspHomeComponent},
        { path: '**', component: WaspHomeComponent}
    ]},
    { path: '**', component: ChoseBugHomeComponent }
];
```

This way, your user will be redirected to any bug home, no matter the route. And if he inputs no route at all, he will be redirected to a component that "allows" him to chose which bug to chose